# Why does the CartPole-v0 reset after 200 steps?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I was working on CartPole-v0 provided by openai gym. I noticed that my program always resets after 200 steps. If I sum all the rewards from an episode, where the maximum reward is 1.0 for each timestep, I never get more than 200. I was wondering if there is any configuration I might have missed in the gymlibrary gym. Has anybody found this problem?

Answer (score 9):

`CartPole-v0` gives a reward of `1.0` for every step your agent is "alive".

The environment is registered with these lines of code:

```
register(
    id='CartPole-v0',
    entry_point='gym.envs.classic_control:CartPoleEnv',
    max_episode_steps=200,
    reward_threshold=195.0,
)
```

which, in the current version of the repository, can be found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/__init__.py#L53).

That `max_episode_steps=200` means that an episode automatically terminates after `200` steps. So, the maximum score you can get is `200`.

Comment: I've solved with **`env._max_episode_steps = 500`** as found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/463#issuecomment-389873434). Calling **`env.reset()`** will also reset the score, so you may wanto to write a **`def env_reset():`** function as well.